# Online resources for special relativity

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

I wasn't sure where to post this, but I'm on a mathematics course that has basically brushed over special relativity. I'm also doing an out of department module called philosophy of physics and as you might expect it doesn't go very deep into the mathematics of it either. I would like to learn it rigorously, but I don't have any resources. I'm looking for recommendations (textbooks e.t.c.) that are available online (I'm pretty handy at finding electronic versions of textbooks but some just aren't available online and I don't have access to the library at the moment). Thanks for any replies!

Comment: When I was in college (late 1970s), Taylor and Wheeler's **Spacetime physics** was the gold standard. Also, most any sophomore level (in the U.S.) Modern Physics text had a decent chapter or two on special relativity.

Comment: I like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Special-Relativity-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852334266/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1391790798&sr=1-5&keywords=special+relativity) book for the math side, though it is not an online resource.

Comment: I'm going to second Wheeler's Space time physics. If you want a *deep* understanding of SR this is the way to go.

Comment: http://nptel.ac.in/courses/115101011/#tab2

Comment: Thanks for all the replies! I'm going to check out all these resources today, I'll let you know how I found them later

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps these  texts might be useful:

[Motion Mountain](http://www.motionmountain.net/)  by Christoff Schiller

[Light and Matter](http://www.lightandmatter.com/) by Ben Crowell

Answer (score 1):

In undergrad my professor for Special and General relativity posted some lecture notes by Sean Carrol which are very good. They cover the full theory so they may be a bit much to handle.

[- Short Lecture Notes](http://physics.fsu.edu/courses/Fall13/PHZ4601/small_gr_notes.pdf)

[- Long Lecture Notes](http://physics.fsu.edu/courses/Fall13/PHZ4601/gr_notes.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a course by Susskind in Stanford university:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD9DDFBDC338226CA

Of course, you can also find them in itune.

I think it would be very helpful.