# reference for special relativity

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request, special-relativity

I got a student finishing its first year of Math and she would like to study a bit of special relativity from a mathematics point of view. I know the subject quite well but I don't know any basic references. what I look for her his some basic on Minkowsky? and if possible the Maxwell equation from the differential form point of view? Of course she don't know differential form yet, but she is motivated to learn. any idea willbe welcome. Thx!

Comment: Somewhat relevant --- [Online resources for special relativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667531/online-resources-for-special-relativity) AND [Special Relativity-Book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812716/special-relativity-book)

Answer (score 2):

There is a really lovely book by David Bressoud called Second Year Calculus: From Celestial Mechanics to Special Relativity.  He is an excellent writer and the book is a joy to read.  It gives the gentlest introduction to differential forms and special relativity that you could hope for.

https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387976068

Answer (score 1):

I never took a course on relativity, but I enjoyed these video lectures
on YouTube:

[Frederic P Schuller: A thorough introduction to the theory of general relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G4SqIboeig&list=PLFeEvEPtX_0S6vxxiiNPrJbLu9aK1UVC_)

Having 13 lectures mainly devoted to geometry, it is maybe not suited as a quick introduction to the topic and feels more like a math course than a physics lecture. But there are many side remarks on how differential geometry and physics are connected and it is very rigorous from a mathematical point of view.